# arweave-sol option is not working well when uploading images for mainnet-beta on solana

Tags: upload, storage, solana, metaplex

I'm going to upload images to arweave-sol storage for mainnet-beta on solana, but am encountering on errors everytimes.
I have now 1.2 sol and know it's enough to upload images.
The errors are following.

```
wallet public key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Beginning the upload for 2 (img+json) pairs
started at: 1644902774661
initializing candy machine
initialized config for a candy machine with publickey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Uploading Size 2 { mediaExt: '.png', index: '0' }
Saved bundle upload result to cache.
Computed Bundle range, including 2 file pair(s) totaling 0.014MB.
Uploading bundle via bundlr... in multiple transactions
0.000002188 SOL to upload
Failed bundlr upload, automatically retrying transaction in 10s (attempt: 1) Error: Not enough funds to send data
    at NodeUploader.dataItemUploader (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/node_modules/@bundlr-network/client/build/common/upload.js:43:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async uploadTransaction (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/upload/arweave-bundle.ts:520:13)
    at async processBundle (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/upload/arweave-bundle.ts:535:11)
    at async uploadV2 (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/commands/upload.ts:202:11)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:190:7)
Failed bundlr upload, automatically retrying transaction in 10s (attempt: 2) Error: Not enough funds to send data
    at NodeUploader.dataItemUploader (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/node_modules/@bundlr-network/client/build/common/upload.js:43:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async uploadTransaction (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/upload/arweave-bundle.ts:520:13)
    at async /home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/upload/arweave-bundle.ts:531:15
    at async uploadTransaction (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/upload/arweave-bundle.ts:520:13)
    at async processBundle (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/upload/arweave-bundle.ts:535:11)
    at async uploadV2 (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/commands/upload.ts:202:11)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:190:7)
upload was not successful, please re-run. Error: Not enough funds to send data
    at NodeUploader.dataItemUploader (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/node_modules/@bundlr-network/client/build/common/upload.js:43:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async uploadTransaction (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/upload/arweave-bundle.ts:520:13)
    at async /home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/upload/arweave-bundle.ts:531:15
    at async uploadTransaction (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/upload/arweave-bundle.ts:520:13)
    at async /home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/upload/arweave-bundle.ts:531:15
    at async uploadTransaction (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/upload/arweave-bundle.ts:520:13)
    at async processBundle (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/upload/arweave-bundle.ts:535:11)
    at async uploadV2 (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/commands/upload.ts:202:11)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/home/user/solana-mint/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:190:7)
```

how can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have fund on your wallet
" Error: Not enough funds to send data"
send sol to the address of your default file wallet
(make sure solana cli is installed then "solana address" will give you the address of your default wallet. the path of the default wallet is displayed when you type "solana config get")